# How to avoid read same input twice when do UNION in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

[DAG screen cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x3lj.jpg)

I have one large file to process, before any projections and union, i do a repartition on input dataframe (from small partition to larger partition since the input over 10gb), but from DAG, we can see the input has been read and repartition twice which is very costly. Not sure is there any optimize method i can do to avoid that, i tried to cache after repartition which seems not able to avoid this.
Details could refer to attached pic of DAG, Thanks

Comment: Is it only one file or many files ? Which format ? Have you tried using `.coalesce` instead of `.repartition`

Comment: It maybe due to `cache` is lazy, so you can try call `count` after cache.

Comment: coalesce is for reduce partitions, here i need increase partitions.  The file is actually parquet. @RobertoCongiu

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's how unions work, it will run the transformations independently and read the same input for each DataFrame in the union (when doing self-unions).

What exactly is it that you're trying to do in the union? Have you considered flatMap or the explode function instead?

Comment: I have a table which is "src" and "dst", i'm trying to extract a table of "vertex". (combine of "src" and "dst" as "vertex"

Comment: Not sure I follow why you need a union for that. Why can't you just combine the src and dst columns into a struct or array?

Comment: Hi, its like vertex in graph. I'm thinking of combine as an array, then explode, but i need revise the fwd_bytes and rev_bytes which is not easily perform on simple explode.

Comment: I think you could do this with explode or flatMap and maybe a window if you need lag/lead type of function, but I would avoid self-union with a large data set.